# OnMeasure's heightMeasureSpec not set after explicitly calling setLayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view that I am inflating for a `ListView`, and I am attempting to set the exact width and height of it. However it is failing on `API 17: 4.2.2` despite working on newer APIs. This is my adapter's `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    convertView = getInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, parent, false);
    CustomImageView image = (CustomImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_image);
    image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 200));

    return convertView;
}
```

And this is the view's `onMeasure()`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
    }
    else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Using the debugger, I can see that `widthMeasureSpec` is correct (the width is right, and `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` is set.) On newer API levels, the`heightMeasureSpec` is also correct. **However**, I recently tried `API 17`, and found that the `heightMeasureSpec` value that gets passed is `0` (the equivalent of `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`).

Are there any insights as to why this isn't working on `API 17`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out the cause of the unexpected behaviour, but I did a hacky work-around instead.

Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    convertView = getInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, parent, false);
    CustomImageView image = (CustomImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_image);
    image.setDimensions(new Point(300, 200));
    image.requestLayout();

    return convertView;
}
```

And the `CustomImageView`:

```
private Point _point;
public void setDimensions(Point p) {
    _point = p;
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (_point != null) {
        setMeasuredDimension(p.x, p.y);
    }
    else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to some changes have been made in view drawing in this api, i faced this stange behaviour too. Try to use [ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html).

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        view.getX();
        view.getY();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In onWindowFocusChanged are already loaded the UI elements. 
You can get the data there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why API17 alone is behaving differently (hopefully a bug, perhaps). But seems like the issue might be in the scrolling vertical behavior of the ListView as only Height is affected in this. Probably in this case, specified height is not considered and "wrap_content" is chosen.

But I hope by now you have a workaround for this. If not then you could just go ahead and handle the `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` case in the `onMeasure()` too.

In my custom views, I always make sure that I handle all the cases: **UNSPECIFIED**, **EXACTLY** and **AT_MOST**.

Comment: @RogueBaneling Could you do a small change in your code and check the result? Change the layout_height of  the view 'list_view_image' to 200dp in the list_view_layout.xml . I suspect that you have given the layout_height of this as 'wrap_content'. Just wanted to check if the layoutParams is getting set correctly in case of API17.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I've posted my work-around here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33181704/3358186. Your post didn't really answer my question about _why_ `API17` is failing but I have a feeling that it won't end up getting answered, and I think that you have put the most effort in so I will award you the bounty.